# What is the document class / package of this pdf file?

Tags: packages, document-classes

Does anyone know the name of the package / documentstyle used [here](http://www.tcs.uni-luebeck.de/lehre/2010-ws/logik/wiki/Vorlesung?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=logik-skript-ws2010.pdf)?

I think the style must be public, because I saw another file by another author using it (but I can't publish this document here).

Comment: To know for sure, ask [Till](http://www.tcs.uni-luebeck.de/mitarbeiter/tantau/) or this other author you mention.

Comment: Most likely a custom made one.

Comment: I wish my logic notes had been that good-looking.

Comment: I've sent the author an email and will report back if he tells me how this document was typeset.

Comment: Just to report back: I sent out an email to the author Till Tantau but didn't receive an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can start looking at [beamerexample-lecture-print-version.pdf](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/examples/beamerexample-lecture-print-version.pdf). It's not exactly like the one you show, but it's similar. Even more, you will  find the `.tex` source in your computer with your `beamer` package.