# beamer: How to make an outline document with modified frame environment

Tags: beamer, environments

In LaTeX Beamer there is the frame environment that can be used to put certain information on a slide. I want to create an outline document where the frame environment is replaced by something else.

I tried doing so by defining new commands `\newcommand{\beginframe}{\begin{frame}}` and `\newcommand{\endframe}{\end{frame}}` however I get errors that suggest that you cannot put environment commands in new commands.

Can I abstract away the frame environment in such a way, that I can just remove the environment?

I would prefer not to use `\newtheorem{frame}` to have lots of frame environments then that are possibly numbered.

Comment: If 'where the frame environment is replaced by something else' means that you want your frames be typeset in another way, then may be `beamerarticle` can help you. Look at my answer to [What is the document class / package of this pdf file?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/38616/1952)

Comment: @Ignasi: that actually looks quite good. Unfortunately it fails to compile right now due to a clash in the colour package. I will look into that! Thank you very much

Comment: `beamerarticle` doesn't like beamer colors (look [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/22768/1952)). Beamer manual section 'Compatibility with other packages and classes' explain how to use `color` and `xcolor`.